# Nodejs pipe memory increase dramatically

Tags: node.js

I'm using Nodejs pipe to send data from other server to client, but memory usage of nodejs increasing every minute and I don't know why.

```js
app.use("/", function(req, res) {
  try {
    var serviceAddress = "http://example.com";
    req
      .pipe(
        request(serviceAddress, function(error, response, body) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("error:", error);
            res.status(410).end();
          }
        }),
      )
      .pipe(res)
      .on("error", function(e) {
        console.log("***Error in pipe:\r\n" + e);
        res.destroy();
      });
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log("***Error in run: \r\n" + ex);
    res.status(410).end();
  }
});
app.listen(81, () => {});
```

Comment: Is the memory actually in use, or is it free but reserved by the garbage collector? https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage

Comment: I checked windows task manager and memory is not available(in using).